# JWT token exchange via named credentials as per user

Tags: jwt, salesforce, mulesoft

I am trying to generate a JSON Web Token(JWT) via named credentials as per user.
I want to use this named creds for authentincation purpose. **So that using them after salesforce providing JSON web token, in exchange my local auth server will provide a token.**

Below are the settings I have added while creating the named credentials as per user.

> **Label** : TestJWTCredential
>
> **Name** : TestJWTCredential
>
> **URL** : -> external-endpoint <-
>
> ***In Authentication Part***
>
> **Certificate** : MulesoftJWT
>
> **Identity Type** : Per User
>
> **Authentication Protocol** : JWT Token Exchange
>
> **Token Endpoint Url** : http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token
>
> **Scope** : refresh_token full
>
> **Issuer** : -> my-username <-
>
> **Per User Subject** : $userId
>
> **Audience** : http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token
>
> **Token Valid for** : 1 Hours
>
> **JWT Signing Certificate** : MulesoftJWT

**Ref** :- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5#language-combobox

"*http://localhost:8091/api/provider/token*" **This is the url of my authorization server which is a mule application deployed on my local.**

Also while calling this named creds from developer console, it gives this error
System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange.
Below is the APEX code,

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:TestJWTCredential/services/oauth2/userinfo');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer'+ UserInfo.getSessionId());
Http http = new Http();
System.debug('REQUEST :::: ' + req);
HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);
System.debug('RESPONSE  :::: ' + resp.getBody());
```

Can any body help me how to do it.

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: @asitm9
System.CalloutException: Unable to complete the JWT token exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I was just viewing some Salesforce videos on this topic. In the "Deep Dive into Salesforce Connected App - Part 3" video, at the 23:56 mark, the Salesforce presenter had to delete the "scope" value to get it to work. https://youtu.be/wN8d4vwSA-E?t=1436